# Selecting part does not seem on blender. No wireframe edges

Tags: edges, selection-tools, wireframe

I am using blender 2.8 as you can see on the picture. There was an issue with evee render. Blender was crashing. After that, I reinstalled driver then it ran well. 
But in edit mode, I can see any selecting part. in wireframe mode, edges does not seem as well. 
Additionally, there is a black area at right bottom. You can see on picture. 
Waiting for help. 
Thanks

[image: Blender issue]

Answer (score 1):

Did you accidentally enable the clipping border?

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to clear it

[image: View Clip]

Comment: No. I checked it. Not about it. I think it is about graphic card driver. That must be a bug.